# Get joomla loginsession from another php page on a different server

Tags: php, joomla

I need to catch the loginsession from a joomla webpage and call that from a website a wrote which lies on a different server.

This is what i tried:

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) 
{
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
}

defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->groups;


if($user->id)
{
    if (isset($groups[7]) or isset($groups[8])) 
    {
        echo $user->username;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'false';
    }   
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

I uploaded this into the root folder of the joomla site. If I call it via browser it works perfectly. It returns the username when i'm logged in and returns false when i'm logged out.

If I call it from the php Page it returns `false`

```
$siteText= file_get_contents ("http://examplejoomlasite.org/miniphpscript.php");
```

Is there any other chance to catch the joomla loginsession on another page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your call is a server request. Means it looks like for the miniphpscript if you would open a browser on your server it doesn't know anything about browser session on your local computer.

You should use a better HTTP library like Guzzle http://guzzlephp.org, which comes with cookie support. You have then to log in trough Guzzle first and save the cookie as file. On all your subsequent requests to the miniphpscript you need to use that cookie then.

Comment: is there a chance to catch the original login, not the guzzle login?

Answer (score 0):

After going through your question again and again I concluded that you need user integration on both the servers. that means you can know the user data in another server.
Go for jfusion to have common user in both the websites; provided both are php based. Link to JFusion is http://www.jfusion.org/feature/what-is-jfusion . If your system is based on any of the listed frameworks like dokuwiki, phpbb3 forum, kayako support OR joomla itself, then you can easily integrate it. Also if you have any other framework with which you want user integration then you can create a jfusion plugin. Jfusion works seamlessly with the frameworks i stated above.

You can check their documentation to create your custom JFusion Plugin http://www.jfusion.org/docs/doku.php?id=dev;intro

Comment: the second php site is 100% selfmade and there is no cms behind it, so the integration is quite hard I guess?
I don't really need the users on the second site, i just want to catch the same session. If the session is active, there are some "adminbuttons" on the page.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to develop a small webservice on your server that will just update a table in your database with authentications on the Joomla website.

Then, you will need to develop a small Joomla plugin which is triggered on authentication that will call the webservice and update it the login information.

Comment: i wouldn't say thats easy